# How to move scroll programmatically to Scroll View, when the text no longer fits on the screen?

Tags: xamarin.forms, scrollview

good day, I'm having a problem with a scroll view, I have a label in a horizontal scroll view, that label concateno amounts, the problem is when the text no longer fit on the screen, the scroll does not move, and I would like if I enter a new quantity in the label, the scroll scrolls so that the last added quantity can be visible, I hope you can help me

This is my XAML:

```
<ScrollView x:Name="SV" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
     <Label Text="{Binding FullSumList}" TextColor="#000000"  FontSize="{extensions:ScalableFont 30}" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />  
</ScrollView>
```

I searched, not to find a solution

there if I write a quantity, should the scroll go to the left, so that the new quantity is seen

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ScrollToAsync method.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scroll-view)

In your xaml

```
 <ScrollView x:Name="SV" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
     <Label x:Name="labelTest" Text="{Binding FullSumList}" TextColor="#000000"  FontSize="{extensions:ScalableFont 30}" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />  
</ScrollView>
```

In the code-behind

```
SV.ScrollToAsync(labelTest, ScrollToPosition.End, true);
```